# Server Side and Client Side - when can we place php inside javascript?

Tags: php, ajax, client-side, server-side

Let's say we have something among those lines:

```
  $.ajax({
     success: function(html){
     $("#related_events").append(html);
     $("#related_events").fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150); //optional
     type: 'get',
     url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('related'); ?>',
```

Specifically on this line lies the question:

```
 url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('related'); ?>',
```

Will that echo be executed, by taking into consideration this ajax call ?
OR
That echo will be ALWAYS executed, because on that time the server side has been already triggered ?

What if I have this conditional BEFORE the ajax call, would that echo be executed taking into consideration that if?

Looking at the browser output is of no use I believe, because, we get that echo, but we don't know if, we get that echo because it will run ALWAYS, or it will run conditionally.

```
if('<?= $something ?>' == 'create'){
                $("#Event_name").focusout(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                          success: function(html){
                          $("#related_events").append(html);
                          $("#related_events").fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150); //optional
                    }, 
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('related'); ?>',
                    data:
                    {
                       ind: $('#Event_name').val()
                    },

                    beforeSend: function(){
                                            $("#related_events").empty();
                                        },
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'html'
                });
              })
            }
```

I'm sure this is something related with my bad compreenshion about the server/client side process here.

**Update:**

I understand that the php code will get executed. What I'm not getting is:

**1)** Will he know about the javascript conditional ?

**2)** Will it get evaluated differently if we are on an ajax call ?

(struggling here...)

Comment: Make sure by viewing the HTML source in your browser.

Comment: So this means that you are conditionally trying to execute JS code? is it through your condition above? if('<?= $something ?>' == 'create'){}

Comment: @verisimilitude : yes. But more then that, I'm trying to understand if this makes sense, or if it doesn't. And if there's a difference between echo a php inside a simple javascript OR calling a php inside an ajax call. (simple javascript means, obviously, that I'm lost on the proper terminology).

Answer (score 3):

PHP is compiled on the server before it's shown to the client. So that URL will be generated and will be viewable in the source as whatever your createURL function outputs.

Comment: The question is: 1) will it take into consideration the conditional ? and 2) is it different to echo a php on a ajax call versus non-ajax javascript code ?

Answer (score 1):

If that  tag is inside a PHP file (i.e. a file which will be processed before the response is sent to browser), it will be executed.

If it is in a separate JS file, or inside a HTML File (static files), then it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP will render when the page loads, the browser has no idea what PHP code is there, it is delivered as HTML from the server. Then the javascript executes on the client-side. So if you view the page's source you should see the created URL by PHP. In other words, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Marcus Recck's answer above. PHP is compiled and the response is returned and therefore the above URL will be viewable.

A good idea here is to check your browser for JavaScript errors. Different browsers have different ways of showing this, but look for a javascript console or something like that. Also, check the source of your page as viewed by the browser. This is to ensure that things work as you expect them to when you mingle these together.

```
url: 'createUrl('related'); ?>',
```

should be

```
url: "createUrl('related'); ?>",
```

I feel...